# python - type error

Tags: python

this is my code:

```
def get_num():
    number = int(raw_input(" ")),
    print "|"
    return number
list_of_letter = ['a',   'b',   'c',    'd',    'e',    'f',    'g',    'h',    'i',    'j',    'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's' 't' 'u' 'v' 'w' 'x' 'y' 'z']
num = -1
print "welcome to the sudoko maker!!!"
print "I will start asking you information."
for lines in range (9):
    for ask in range(9):
        if num == 25:
             num = 0
        num = num + 1             
        print list_of_letter [num],
    print
```

and when I run it python writes:
IndexError: list index out of range
why????

Comment: don't waste question marks uselessly!

Comment: @Guandalino: Hey, don't be so quick to judge. Maybe Python 3.4 changes the default error description for `IndexError` from `'list index out of range'` to `'list index out of range why???'`. :)

Comment: @Roey, mine is not an answer but still can be helpful: for this kind of issues consider to use a Python module called [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). It's the debugger (basically you'll use `pdb.set_trace()` and some keys like l, n, c, s, and so on). It's a very didactic, self aid and not too complex tool. If you still have problems add details to your question sharing your discoveries. Maybe some downvote will disappear, too.

Comment: This should have been closed as a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a couple of commas from the `list_of_letter` list; there are no commas starting from element `'k'` onwards. As a result, `list_of_letter` does not have 25 items, but only 11.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, but you still need to explain _why_ he's getting this error: he has an 11th "letter" `'klmnopqrstuvwxyz'` and no more after that, because adjacent strings are concatenated.

Comment: No need to write all those characters. Just use `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Comment: +1 Matthias. And if you really want a `list` (which you probably don't, because `ascii_lowercase[3]` is the same `'d'` as `list_of_letters[3]`), you can just use `list(string.ascii_lowercase)`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tamas answer, it would be easier to read and function the same if you made `list_of_letter` a single string (which can be indexed the same way):

```
list_of_letter = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Comment: This is the same thing as `string.ascii_lowercase`, but easier to get wrong.